# How to instantiate multiple mqtt clients in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, asynchronous, console

With the php mqtt client library it is possible to connect to a mqtt broker and hold the connection.
This is done with a `loopForever()` method. Whenever the client is receiving something, a callback method is called.

If you would directly instantiate this client in your normal source code (controller, business model or whatever) you would unavoidable run into the infinite loop. 
The only way seems to run it in an extra php process. In symfony this can be done by wrapping it in a console command.

If i want to know if this or multiple client connections are still alive, what is the best approach to control the status? How can i look into the process from symfony to make sure, that the client is still connected?

My intention is to make the client or multiple clients configurable in a symfony backend, start them automatically and watch their status all the time.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [`supervisord`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html#supervisor-configuration).